# A Measure Theory problem-If $\int_{A_n}f(x)dx\rightarrow0 $ then $\lambda(A_n)\rightarrow0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

This question was proposed as part of a test for PhD applicants but considered too hard and rejected. I tried unsucessfully to solve it for quite some time. For anyone wishing to try his luck..

> Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be a measurable, almost everywhere strictly positive function. Also let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of countable subsets of $[0,1]$ such that for $n\rightarrow\infty$ we have $$\int_{A_n}f(x)dx\rightarrow0 $$
>
> Show that for $n\rightarrow\infty$ we also have $$\lambda(A_n)\rightarrow0$$

Comment: I think the word "countable" needs to be moved two words to the left.

Comment: @UmbertoP. You mean countable sequence? Hmm.It was given like that. I will check my notes once again but I believe the above form is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. For each $k \in \mathbb N$ define $E_k = \{x : f(x) > 1/k\}$. Then $E_1 \subset E_2 \subset \cdots$ and the union of the $E_k$'s is the whole interval $[0,1]$. Thus $\lambda(E_k) \to \lambda([0,1])$ so there exists an index $k$ satisfying $\lambda(E_k) > 1 - \epsilon$ and thus $\lambda([0,1] \setminus E_k) < \epsilon$.

For any index $n$ you get
 $$\lambda (A_n) = \lambda(A_n \cap E_k) + \lambda(A_n \setminus E_k)$$
where
$$\lambda(A_n \cap E_k) = \int_{A_n \cap E_k} \, dx \le k \int_{A_n} f(x) \, dx$$
and
$$ \lambda(A_n \setminus E_k) \le \lambda([0,1] \setminus E_k) < \epsilon.$$
Since $\displaystyle \int_{A_n} f(x) \, dx \to 0$ you get $\limsup \lambda(A_n) \le \epsilon.$ Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary you get $\lambda(A_n) \to 0.$

Comment: Excellent! +1 Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You have now (I hate to say it: unofficially) passed an (I even more hate to say it:) unknown part of an admission test for a PhD application (at a university also unknown) ;-)  Anyway, +1

Comment: @Thomas It is true! I did not come up with it for a "dramatic effect" or so to speak..

Comment: @Umberto  $\lambda(A_n \setminus E_k) \le \lambda(E_k)<\epsilon$  should be replaced with  $\lambda(A_n \setminus E_k) \le \lambda([0,1] \setminus E_k)<\epsilon$

Comment: @GogiPantsulaia Thanks!